# Stop beginning transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

(Example) So, I have transitions for let's say, the `<p>` element of my site. `.invert` switches it from red to blue. I have a JS function named `invert()` and it runs right away, but I want `invert()` to switch it without transitions if it's done on page load.

```js
elm = document.getElementById("invert");

function invert() {
  elm.classList.toggle("invert");
}

invert();
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
  font-size: 150%;
  transition: color 1s;
}

p.invert {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="invert">peanut</p>
<button onclick="invert()">butter</button>
```

The code snippet isn't doing it but you get the idea! :P Just imagine there's a transition when the code runs, when I call `invert()` so that it actually switches from red to blue. I can give you the code to the site if you want.

Help would be much appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: mtm828.github.io See how it toggles dark mode if you had dark mode enabled last time you visited the site? I want to stop the transition if it's doing that.

Comment: why nit applying the invert class initially?

Comment: @TemaniAfif wdym? Also this is just an example, what I'm really trying to do is in mtm828.github.io.

Comment: `<p class="invert" id="invert">peanut</p>`

Comment: @SnareHanger Um no that wouldn't do for my dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unset the transition just before invert the color then set it again:

```
elm.style.transition = '0s';
invert();
elm.style.transition = 'color 1s';
```